# I have an issue with sql query to extract install date of software in computer

Tags: sql-server, sccm, qsqlquery

I have a SQL query that will query for all the products installed on a computer, with the product publisher, name, and version. I have been trying to get the installed dates of the programs but since I'm a newbie at this, I'm really bad at this. So far they only extract the Product company, name and version. I need the dates of when they were installed in the computer.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    SYS.Netbios_Name0, SYS.Rsqlesource_Domain_OR_Workgr0,
    SP.CompanyName, SP.ProductName, SP.ProductVersion
FROM 
    fn_rbac_GS_SoftwareProduct(@UserSIDs) SP 
JOIN 
    fn_rbac_R_System(@UserSIDs) SYS ON SP.ResourceID = SYS.ResourceID 
WHERE
    SYS.Netbios_Name0 LIKE @variable  
ORDER BY 
    SP.CompanyName, SP.ProductName, SP.ProductVersion
```

Comment: You need to find the table and field that contains this value. You need to open up the database and start searching for likely fields. What does `select * from dbo.fn_rbac_GS_SoftwareProduct(@UserSIDs)` return?

Comment: I dont have access to Sql studio, which Im used to using, instead Im using sql builder. I tried to run the query there and the only things that came up where "ResourceID, ProductID, CompanyName, ProductName, ProductVersion and ProductLanguage. @Nick.McDermaid

Comment: I googled and found this at reddit of all places https://www.reddit.com/r/SCCM/comments/5ug55z/wql_query_for_installed_application_with/ Do you have an object called `SMS_G_System_INSTALLED_SOFTWARE`?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid i tried to select * from SMS_G_System_INSTALLED_SOFTWARE but it came back with an error saying "An error occurred while executing the query. Invalid object name SMS_G_System_INSTALLED_SOFTWARE' and returned an error:208

Comment: Well I'm out of ideas

Comment: The tables starting with SMS are always on the WMI side of the SCCM DB, they have slightly different names on the SQL side, but there is probably an equivalent there (like 99% of the time there is). It's probably called something like v_gs_installed_software  or the like but I can look that up for you tomorrow when I'm back at the office.

Comment: alright, thank you! @Syberdoor

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Im stumped as well

Comment: You need to find a data dictionary for the System Centre Configuration Manager database (i.e. google it). Or at least list out and go through all of the views that you can see. If you can't use SQL Server Management studio to browse objects, then you can run a query like this to find likely columns (if you have access) `select OBJECT_NAME(object_id) as tbl, [name] as columnname from sys.columns where [name] LIKE '%date%' OR [name] LIKE '%inst%'`

Comment: OK I looked it up and unfortunately it seems there is no flawless solution. v_gs_installed_software exists but is empty, v_GS_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS has the install date but unlike fn_rbac_GS_SoftwareProduct it is an inventory of hklm\software\microsoft\windows\currentversion\uninstall so it does not list software that is installed for only one user. In our work environment this would never be a problem but I don't know if it is ok for you. If it is fine for you as well I can write an answer with more detail

Comment: @Syberdoor I wouldnt mind trying anything at this point.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what exactly the base for whatever is inventoried in fn_rbac_GS_SoftwareProduct (or v_GS_SoftwareProduct for that matter) is but unfortunately it does not include the installation dates.

There are two views

> v_GS_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS

and

> v_GS_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS64

that get populated with the data from

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall

and

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall

respectively. They might be of use to you, although they have several caveats.

- First of all as they come from the local machine part of the registry
  they would not include software that was installed for only one user
  (In MSI this is the Option "Install for Everyone" vs "Install only
  for me").
- Second you have to use both if you want the full information because one will only contain 32Bit programs and one only 64Bit programs.
- Finally although they do include the field InstallDate it is literally based on the REG_SZ InstallDate in one of those keys and this is neither a mandatory field, nor a standardized one. This means A Program is basically allowed to just create it's uninstall key and not use this property. If it is created there is also no guarantee that the format will always we the same (e.g. in our company I found two formats YYYYMMDD and MM-DD-YYY) so if you want to process this column further you might have to sanitize it.

While this all sounds a little hopeless, it is perfectly possible that for a given scenario it is no problem at all. For example if you install all your applications as msi via sccm it is fair to assume that the InstallDate key will allways be present and in the same format.

The full query for this would be something like

```
SELECT 
    SYS.Name0, ARP.DisplayName0, ARP.Publisher0, ARP.InstallDate0 
FROM 
    v_GS_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS ARP 
LEFT JOIN 
    v_R_System SYS ON SYS.ResourceID = ARP.ResourceID 
WHERE 
    SYS.Name0 = @variable 
AND NOT 
    (ARP.DisplayName0 like '%Update%' OR ARP.DisplayName0 like '%Service Pack%')
UNION 
SELECT 
    SYS.Name0, ARP.DisplayName0, ARP.Publisher0, ARP.InstallDate0 
FROM 
    v_GS_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS_64 ARP 
LEFT JOIN 
    v_R_System SYS ON SYS.ResourceID = ARP.ResourceID 
WHERE 
    SYS.Name0 = @variable 
AND NOT 
    (ARP.DisplayName0 like '%Update%' OR ARP.DisplayName0 like '%Service Pack%')
```

Note that I included some filter against Windows updates which would be included as well. Also I did not use the rbac functions but rather the views directly, I hope that is ok.